# Access tables names in middleware in a single transaction

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say CRUD operations are performed on three tables in a single controller method.

Is it possible for me to get all the tables names on which CRUD operations are performed in the middleware.

As of now, when I submit a form I can only access those inputs from the request in the middleware, but when I insert three records into three different tables in a single controller action am not able to access the table names in the middleware.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to get table name automatically. You will have to right custom logic in middleware for that controller action. Because the response object we get in middleware after the execution of controller method is html, json, etc response which is to be sent to client.